# Package a python project that contains a .so library

Tags: python, python-module

I want to package my python project using [this official tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/)

The problem is that my project uses a .so external library. When I make a package and import it in a random python script, i get this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myExternalLib'

I couldn't find any tutorial on how to add an external library to my package, I think I'm not searching with the right keywords.

Comment: The guide you linked only covers pure Python code. You will need to refer to the [Packaging binary extensions](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-binary-extensions/) guide, and given that's an incomplete guide please refer to all the links.  For a quick example on how this is done, refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48706842/python-3-x-c-extension-module-and-submodule).

Comment: Thank you for your pointers. I found a lot of great material for implementing C extension. But after exploring the guide and all the links that looked interesting, I honestly found nothing relevant to my issue.

Comment: I am not trying to compile an extension. I have an extension that is already compiled, and I want to tell the setup file to add it to the package.

Comment: You may try using [a `MANIFEST.in`](https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-manifest-in/) file to forcibly include the `*.so` files.  This is not guaranteed to work as it isn't a portable solution, but if you don't care then this might address your requirements.

Comment: Do note that any other actually external `.so` library files that reside outside of your package (e.g. `/usr/lib/my_shared_lib.so`), there is no supported method to include them with a Python package file of any kind.

Comment: @metatoaster I found the solution that best fits my needs. Thanks a lot for your help and advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is to add the external library as a package data.

```
setup(
    ..... 
    packages=['myLib'],
    package_data={'myLib': ['myExternalLib.so']},
)
```